Package 'snapd' has no installation candidate on Linux Mint when wanting to update it
This is after installation using apt-get on my Raspberry Pi 4B running Debian Bookworm:
root@rpi4:/root# apt-cache policy snapd
snapd:
  Installed: 2.57.6-1+b5
  Candidate: 2.57.6-1+b5
  Version table:
 *** 2.57.6-1+b5 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

and this is the output from my Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon:
$ apt-cache policy snapd
snapd:
  Installed: 2.45.1+20.04
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     2.63+22.04 -10
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.58+22.04.1 -10
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.55.3+22.04 -10
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.45.1+20.04 -10
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ sudo apt-get install snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package snapd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'snapd' has no installation candidate

Is there some problem which needs to be addressed on my Mint, or there is some possibly transient error?

From the Linux Mint docs:

Disabled Snap Store in Linux Mint 20
Following the decision made by Canonical to replace parts of APT with
Snap and have the Ubuntu Store install itself without users knowledge
or consent, the Snap Store is forbidden to be installed by APT in
Linux Mint 20.

Note
For more information read the announcements made in May 2020 and June 2019.

How to install the Snap Store in Linux Mint 20
Recommended or not, if you want to use the Snap Store, re-enabling and
installing it is very easy.
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/nosnap.pref
apt update
apt install snapd


The configuration is still present in LM21. Also, you'd need sudo for all three commands, not just the first one.
